# Inserting and Retrieving data to/from SQLite

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am new to sqllite in android.I am adding records to sql data base, both insert and select query are not giving an runtime error except i have empty cursor on fetching data (on Select Query). let me know if there is a problem in inserting the values or fetching them. As on select query i get the column names but no record.
here is my code.

```
public class SQLHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDb.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private SQLiteDatabase database;

public String stringArray[];
private ArrayList<tasksList> arrayList;

public final static String PROCESS_TABLE = "Process";
public final static String DB_P_ID = "db_process_id";
public final static String PROCESS_ASSIGNMENT_ID = "process_id";
public final static String CASETITLE = "case_title";
public final static String APPEARANCE_DATE = "appearance_date";
public final static String APPEARANCE_TIME = "appearance_time";
public final static String APPEARANCE_REASON = "appearance_reason"; 
public final static String COURT_NAME = "court_name";
public final static String RESPONDENT_NAME = "respondent_name";
public final static String ADDRESS = "address";
public final static String CONTACT_NO = "contact_no";
public final static String CNIC = "cnic";
public final static String NOTICE_NUMBER = "notice_number";

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_PROCESS_TABLE = " CREATE TABLE "+ PROCESS_TABLE + " (db_process_id integer primary key autoincrement," +
        " process_id text not null," +
        " case_title text not null,appearanc e_date text not null ,appearance_time text not null, court_name text not null , respondent_name text not null ," +
        " address text not null ,contact_no text not null ,cnic text not null , appearance_reason text not null , notice_number text not null );";

public SQLHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_PROCESS_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.w(SQLHelper.class.getName(),"Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
            + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Process");
    onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
}

public Boolean insertProcess(String id, String case_Title,String app_date, String app_time, String app_reason,
                           String court_name,String name,String location,String cnic,String notice_no,String contact_no) {

    database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(PROCESS_ASSIGNMENT_ID, id);
    values.put(CASETITLE, case_Title);
    values.put(APPEARANCE_DATE, app_date);
    values.put(APPEARANCE_TIME, app_time);
    values.put(APPEARANCE_REASON, app_reason);
    values.put(COURT_NAME, court_name);
    values.put(RESPONDENT_NAME, name);
    values.put(ADDRESS, location);
    values.put(CONTACT_NO, contact_no);
    values.put(CNIC, cnic);
    values.put(NOTICE_NUMBER, notice_no);
    database.insert(PROCESS_TABLE, null, values);

    return true;

}

public Cursor getCompletedTask(Context applicationContext) {
    Context context = applicationContext;
    database = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] cols = new String[] { CASETITLE};

    Cursor mCursor = database.rawQuery(" Select * from " + PROCESS_TABLE , null);

 //        Cursor mCursor = database.query(true, PROCESS_TABLE, cols, null, null, null, null,  null, null);
    int size = mCursor.getCount();
    stringArray = new String[size];
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!mCursor.isAfterLast()) {
            String id = mCursor.getString(0);
            String title = mCursor.getString(1);

            tasksList fooditem=new tasksList();
            fooditem.setCase_id(id);
            fooditem.setCase_title(title);
            arrayList.add(fooditem);
            mCursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    return mCursor; // iterate to get each value.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you have a space in **`appearanc e_date text not null`** i.e. this should be **`appearance_date text not null`**

Saying that this would in itself not cause a failure it's just that the column name would be **appearanc** rather than appearance_date. This could well cause 
 ensuing confusion (e.g. your likely issue as below).

This is a prime example of why it is recommended to rely on a single source for table and column names. So instead of the corrected :-

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_PROCESS_TABLE = " CREATE TABLE "+ PROCESS_TABLE + " (db_process_id integer primary key autoincrement," +
        " process_id text not null," +
        " case_title text not null,appearance_date text not null ,appearance_time text not null, court_name text not null , respondent_name text not null ," +
        " address text not null ,contact_no text not null ,cnic text not null , appearance_reason text not null , notice_number text not null );";
```

I'd suggest something like :-

```
private static final String CREATE_PROCESS_TABLE = 
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
                PROCESS_TABLE + 
                "(" +
                PROCESS_ASSIGNMENT_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + //NOTE you very likely don't want autoincrement
                CASETITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
                APPEARANCE_DATE + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
                APPEARANCE_TIME + " TEXT NOt NULL," +
                COURT_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                RESPONDENT_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
                ADDRESS + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
                CONTACT_NO + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                CNIC + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
                APPEARANCE_REASON + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
                NOTICE_NUMBER + " TEXT NOT NULL" +
                ")";
```

- reason(s) to not have autoincrement [SQLite Autoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html)

Your issue is probably due to the result of the unintended column name **`appearan`** rather than the expected column name of **`appearance_date`** as the attempt to insert a record will not know about the column **appearance_date** and not insert a row. So you table will be empty.

If you looked at the log you would see something similar to :-

```
05-07 21:13:54.724 1285-1285/? E/SQLiteLog: (1) table Process has no column named appearance_date
```

Correcting as above (removing the unwanted space) deleting the App's data and then rerunning the App should correct that issue.